# Selenium & Beautiful Soup scraping is returning an unexpected result

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The USPTO site offers public data that updates every week. Every time they release new data they release it in a form of " delta data" from the last week. Im trying to download this data using python so I wont have to do it manually every week.

[image]
there are a few weird things that are happening:
[image]

first, the `browser.page_source` holds html (but not the right one - I checked). But when I pass that html (as string) to BeatifulSoup, the `soup.current_data` is empty.

Second, the html that is returning is not the full html and does not contain `delta` or that section at all, even though it is in the site html in the browser:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get that file to download? I need to eventually call the `deltaJsonDownload()` js function.

Code to reproduce:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'https://ped.uspto.gov/peds/'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/bin/phantomjs')
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
assert('delta' in browser.page_source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you analyse the website network calls, it makes an ajax request to get all the links for the data to download.

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://ped.uspto.gov/api/")

data = res.json()

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'message': None,
 'helpText': '{}',
 'xmlDownloadMetadata': [{'lastUpdated': 'Sat 15 Aug 2020 01:30:57-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 10429068701,
   'fileName': 'pairbulk-delta-20200815-xml',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 10:20:10-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 100685778,
   'fileName': '1900-1919-pairbulk-full-20200809-xml',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 10:20:14-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 13877,
   'fileName': '1920-1939-pairbulk-full-20200809-xml',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 10:20:15-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 93016,
   'fileName': '1940-1959-pairbulk-full-20200809-xml',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 10:20:15-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 82353484,
   'fileName': '1960-1979-pairbulk-full-20200809-xml',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 10:20:16-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 5019098918,
   'fileName': '1980-1999-pairbulk-full-20200809-xml',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 10:20:46-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 33231977060,
   'fileName': '2000-2019-pairbulk-full-20200809-xml',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 10:23:23-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 24313575,
   'fileName': '2020-2020-pairbulk-full-20200809-xml',
   'updatedFile': False}],
 'jsonDownloadMetadata': [{'lastUpdated': 'Sat 15 Aug 2020 03:08:00-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 5957650088,
   'fileName': 'pairbulk-delta-20200815-json',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 15:18:23-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 66467976,
   'fileName': '1900-1919-pairbulk-full-20200809-json',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 15:18:25-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 10100,
   'fileName': '1920-1939-pairbulk-full-20200809-json',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 15:18:27-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 69891,
   'fileName': '1940-1959-pairbulk-full-20200809-json',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 15:18:29-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 54076774,
   'fileName': '1960-1979-pairbulk-full-20200809-json',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 15:18:31-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 3009216952,
   'fileName': '1980-1999-pairbulk-full-20200809-json',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 15:18:46-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 18853619536,
   'fileName': '2000-2019-pairbulk-full-20200809-json',
   'updatedFile': False},
  {'lastUpdated': 'Sun 09 Aug 2020 15:20:30-0400',
   'sizeInBytes': 17518389,
   'fileName': '2020-2020-pairbulk-full-20200809-json',
   'updatedFile': False}],
 'links': [{'rel': 'swagger-api-docs', 'href': '/api-docs'}]}
```

Parse the json and using these links you can easily download the file you are looking for. But I would say these files are pretty huge files, better using streaming download in requests.

The link you are looking for is the first element in `data["jsonDownloadMetadata"]`

In order to get the downloadable links, parse the json

```
data = res.json()

for links in data["jsonDownloadMetadata"]:
    print(f"https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName={links['fileName']}")
```

Output:

```
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=pairbulk-delta-20200815-json
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=1900-1919-pairbulk-full-20200809-json
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=1920-1939-pairbulk-full-20200809-json
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=1940-1959-pairbulk-full-20200809-json
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=1960-1979-pairbulk-full-20200809-json
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=1980-1999-pairbulk-full-20200809-json
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=2000-2019-pairbulk-full-20200809-json
https://ped.uspto.gov/api/full-download?fileName=2020-2020-pairbulk-full-20200809-json
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot - thats definitely a better direction than I took. How do I get the actual download link from these file names though? Also, I looked into stream downloading and that is exactly what I will try to do.

Comment: Awesome! Just wondering.. how did you know how are the endpoints called and where to go?

Comment: Open network tab in the chrome developer tools when the website loads